# Trouble detecting the correct data value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this function below to find the `data` value inside of 3 possible DIVs. The data attribute dynamically changes each time that a slide changes position. I am trying to get the correct returned value of `false`, but it incorrectly returns `true` for each slide. What might be the problem?

```
$('.slidelink').on('click', function(e) {
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
    var parent_name = parent[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();
    var parent_tagname = $(parent_name);

    if (parent_tagname.attr('data-isactiveslide') == 'true') {
      alert('working!');
    }
});
```

And the HTML, which represent individual slides in Revolution Slider Wordpress plugin:

```
  <rs-slides>
    <rs-slide data-isactiveslide="false">
      <rs-layer-wrap>
        <rs-loop-wrap>
          <rs-mask-wrap>
            <rs-layer class="slidelink"></rs-layer>
          </rs-mask-wrap>
        </rs-loop-wrap>
      </rs-layer-wrap>
    </rs-slide>
  </rs-slides>
```

Comment: We need to see also html to understand

Comment: You have a reference to the parent.... but you insist on looking it up again? You are selecting all the elements with that tag name and it is reading the first one

Comment: I have added the HTML here, hopefully it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are walking up the tree referencing the element name. Using that to find all the elements in the page with that tag, and looking at the first one.

```
$('.slidelink').on('click', function(e) {
  var parent = $(this).closest("[data-isactiveslide]");
  console.log(parent.data('isactiveslide'))
});
```